# Interpretation of the initial value of an integrator

Tags: continuous-signals, time-series, integration

I came across this example the stream processing chapter of a programming book that I'm reading:

> Streams as signals
>
> We began our discussion of streams by describing them as computational analogs of the signals in signal-processing systems. In fact, we can use streams to model signal-processing systems in a very direct way, representing the values of a signal at successive time intervals as consecutive elements of a stream. For instance, we can implement an integrator or summer that, for an input stream $x = (x_i)$, an initial value $C$, and a small increment $\mathrm{d}t$, accumulates the sum

$$S_i = C + \sum_{j=1}^{i} x_j \ \mathrm{d}t$$

> and returns the stream of values $S = (S_i)$.

This corresponds to the following signal processing system:

[image: ![diagram](https://images.app.goo.gl/69SEhFZ8WXwPKgsL7)]

I don't know anything about signal processing, so I'm not sure quite sure how to interpret the formula shown above for finding $S_i$.

At first I thought it was just the approximation of the solution to the definite integral $\int_0^i f(t) \: \mathrm{d}t$, i.e. $\sum_{j=0}^i x_j \, \Delta t$. But then that would mean $C = x_0 \Delta t$, whereas in the Henderson diagram shown above, the initial value $x_0$ is not scaled by anything.

So, what exactly is $C$? And is it correct to think about $S_i$ as an approximation of $\int_0^i f(t) \: \mathrm{d}t$, i.e. $\sum_{j=0}^i x_j \, \Delta t$?

Comment: geez i really dislike the mathematical notation quoted in this question.  when doing math, formal and proper notation is important.  notation can evolve (like O&S did introducing "$x[n]$" to replace "$x_n$" for a discrete sequence), but mixing a discrete summation (with ridiculous limit notation) with the integral differential "$\mathrm{d}t$" is not good.  I don't wanna pick on the OP, but that book they are quoting is really promoting and propagating horrible notation.

Comment: The summation also just doesn’t make any sense. Is there a typo there?

Comment: @Jdip Sorry, I've fixed it.

Comment: Hmmm still looks funky no? What is the $\sum$ term applied to?

Comment: @Jdip Just to confirm, the corrected version matches what's presented in the book ([link to page](https://web.mit.edu/6.001/6.037/sicp.pdf#page=493)).

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, sorry, I found that a little distracting too. If it helps, here is a link to the relevant page: https://web.mit.edu/6.001/6.037/sicp.pdf#page=493.

Comment: @Jdip, I *think* it's a stream containing the values of some function $f(t)$?

Comment: well, I think that the authors *Harold Abelson* and *Gerald Jay Sussman* have useless and awful taste in mathematical expression.  especially for MIT profs.  there is no excuse for them.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, there is absolutely nothing wrong with a summation over differentials. This is called a differential form. And the linked paper's math notation is correct and there's nothing awful about it. Once again you are assuming that your own limited scope is a relevant reference.

Comment: No, Jazz, you use "$\Delta t$", not "$\mathrm{d}t$".  As in the Riemannian:

$$ \int\limits_a^b f(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum\limits_{n=1}^N f(a+n\Delta x) \ \Delta x \qquad \text{where } \Delta x = \frac{b-a}{N}  $$

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, you are aware that you can, and in fact have to, define the meaning of symbols in math. And there is absolutely nothing wrong with using $dt$ in this case. You are confusing the notation *you would* use with the non-existing notion of a "correct notation". Fortunately, math gives us the freedom to express ideas as we see fit as long as we define the meaning and are logically consistent. But you know better of course, because you took a math class.

Comment: "well, I think that the authors Harold Abelson and Gerald Jay Sussman have useless and awful taste in mathematical expression. especially for MIT profs. there is no excuse for them." [RBJ]. The sheer arrogance in this statement is breath-taking. A normal person would consider that two(!) MIT professors might be educated enough to maybe know a thing or two that escapes their own knowledge. But the certainty with which you dismiss their combined expertise as "useless" and "awful" speaks volumes. Someone who is acting with your authority should really know better than this.

Comment: I understand that I can define symbols to be whatever I want.  They're symbols.  But notation is used to convey information and ideas to others.  And we need some degree of consistency to avoid confusion.  Above, the "$\mathrm{d}x$" on the left side of the equation cannot be used in lieu of the "$\Delta x$" on the right-hand side.  Now, it confuses no one to use "$h$" instead of "$\Delta x$".  But it confuses to use two different meanings for "$\mathrm{d}x$" on both sides of the equal sign.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac _"two(!) MIT professors"_ that really doesn't mean anything. If someone is loudly critiquing 'authoritative' figures, it brings me joy. A Harvard geography professor scrapped his profession because it contradicted the Bible too much. Fox hosts are Ivy graduates. An undergrad can be more trustworthy per being less anchored to a belief system and being less detached from niche-unspecific fundamentals. "S/he's prof. at X with Y pubs" is wind to my ears. It may feel like a pointless lecture on your context-specific point, but I wish emphasize just how little I care for authority.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson No need to strawman, "on both sides of equation" was posed by you, not the text. I dislike the notation, but the context is "+ code", and there's clarity to gain from matching $dt$ with the more code-convenient `dt`. As long as the text makes meaning clear.

Comment: Look at p. 467 of the same document.  Do you see a "$dt$" on that page?  What is the context?

Comment: Talking to yourself? Nice, me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a capacitor:

$$\begin{align}
 v(t) &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{t} \frac{1}{C} \ i(u) \ \mathrm{d}u \\
\\
      &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{0} \frac{1}{C} \ i(u) \ \mathrm{d}u + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{C} \ i(u) \ \mathrm{d}u \\
\\
      &= v(0) + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{C} \ i(u) \ \mathrm{d}u \\
\end{align}$$

The integral at the bottom line has value of zero at $t=0$.

So $v(0)$ is the initial value of the integrator.  If $v(0)=0$, then the capacitor is said to be *uncharged* or *"completely relaxed"* (using control systems semantic) or having zero initial value at $t=0$.

Now if $v(0) \ne 0$, what we were taught in electrical engineering class was to model that as an uncharged capacitor in series with a battery having voltage of the non-zero $v(0)$.  These two are equivalent (the capacitor on the right is uncharged at $t=0$):

[image]

Now what does this mean for an integrator with an initial value in signal processing?  It means that it's identical to an integrator with zero initial value, but with the output of that integrator always having the initial value added to it.  That's how you would code it, if you were representing your integrator as a summation or as a feedback summer.

Comment: Thank you @robert bristow-johnson, I don't have any knowledge of circuits, but I think this answers my question. In the book, we start the summation at $j=1$ (i.e. $\sum_{j=1}^{i} x_j \: \mathrm{\Delta}t$), is this due to the fact that the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{C} \ i(u) \ \mathrm{d}u$ is $0$ at $t=0$? Is it always $0$ at $t=0$?

Comment: Unless it's a dirac delta in the integrad, the integral of any decent function from 0 to 0 has zero width.  If there is zero width, the area is zero.

Answer (score 1):

C is the initial state. This is describing a discrete time accumulator which is the approximation of a continuous time integrator (as determined by mapping the pole at $s=0$ in the Laplace s-plane to a pole at $z=1$ in the z-Transform z-plane).

An accumulator adds the next incoming value to its state using $y[n]= x[n]+ y[n-1]$, with $y[n]$ representing the new state and $y[n-1]$ the previous state. If we started at 0 and kept inputting 1’s the output would count up by 1, holding it’s last state if we stopped inputs, or set the inputs to 0. If we wanted to start again where we left off, with a new simulation, we would need to set C to the last state where we had left off.